# When were numbers first used as code/shorthand for unrelated meanings?

Tags: historical-linguistics, numbers, slang

I was considering [this xkcd](https://xkcd.com/771/), which got me wondering, were there any examples of number based shorthand like “ten-four” in the comic used in the time periods this comic considers “old-timey”?

In other words, what was the first known use of numbers to communicate a meaning entirely unrelated to their numerical values? (i.e. time would not count, as it’s numbers are directly related to the time being communicated) When did this practice start becoming common?
[image: xkcd #771: period speech]

Comment: Number magic is probably too old to be attested historically. Just as an anecdote, 17 is a (very mild) profanity in Swedish because it's 1 less than Odin's number (which was originally a slightly stronger form of profanity).

Comment: What does ten-four mean?

Comment: @Wilson see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ten-code specifically "Ten-codes, officially known as ten signals, are brevity codes used to represent common phrases in voice communication, particularly by law enforcement and in Citizens Band (CB) radio transmissions..." and "...Ten-codes, especially "10-4" (meaning "understood") first reached public recognition in the mid- to late-1950s through the popular television series...". Thanks for asking for that detail, it motivated me to look up the actual origins of the phrase. :)